# Cannot pass double-quoted arguments to php shell

Tags: php, string, shell

I have a long string which consists of command line arguments. The arguments have been wrapped in double-quotes. When I pass in the command to `exec`, nothing happens. I tried passing the string in `escapeshellarg()` before passing into `exec`, but it had no effect.
The string is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/johndoe/src/crm_api.py "jack" "london" "jack@yahoo.com" "09061414145" "No. 1, George St. Ave., CA, USA" "California" "CA" "2222222222" "United States" "$2y$10$U81IfXi7r7hx4xggYTpcJesRblqTKrGAbgM388/v0pH.qtOfLVLfi"
```

The code using the string is as follows:

```
    $command = "/usr/bin/python3 /home/johndoe/src/crm_api.py " .
            $crm_first_name . " " .
            $crm_last_name . " " . $crm_email . " " . $crm_phone . " " .
            $crm_address . " " . $crm_city . " " . $crm_state . " " .
            $crm_zip . " " . $crm_country . " " . $crm_password;

    echo '<script>console.log(\'' . $command . '\');</script>';


    echo $command;
    echo '<script> alert(\'' . $command . '\');</script>';
    $cResult = exec($command);
    echo '<script>console.log(' . $cResult . ');</script>';
```

Comment: `escapeshellarg()` is nowhere in your code. Additionally, injecting strings into JavaScript requires a totally different technique :-?

Comment: The Javascript part is fine causes no issue, logs the string well. The problem is what I pass in to `exec`.

Comment: The problem in the code you've shared is that you should be using `escapeshellarg()` but you aren't doing it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Tried it, it has no effect.

Comment: The function is not broken, not at least on Unix-like platforms. The problem must be on your side. I've composed an answer to illustrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) is the tool to escape shell arguments. E.g.:

```
$script = '/usr/bin/python3 /home/johndoe/src/crm_api.py';
$args = [
    $crm_first_name,
    $crm_last_name,
    $crm_email,
    $crm_phone,
    $crm_address,
    $crm_city,
    $crm_state,
    $crm_zip,
    $crm_country,
    $crm_password,
];
$command = $script . ' ' . implode(' ', array_map('escapeshellarg', $args));
```

(You could also apply it to the script path itself but it isn't necessary here since it's hard-coded.)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/t5MB5)

Comment: Did you click on the word "Demo"? What part is not working?

Comment: The code seems very sane and the resulting command runs well on independent shell, but when used inside `exec()` it does not work.

Comment: So your problem is that when executing certain python script in your home directory using the credentials of whatever user your web server runs as it returns an error code (and possibly an error message). Unfortunately I just answered your question :(